# How to package PySide2 applications for distribution?

Tags: python-3.x, pyside, pyside2

I has used CXFreeze in past to package python applications but in most cases the installer packages build thru CXFreeze failed to install when I distributed it to other users.

Is there a better way to create distributable for Pyside2 applications?

Answer (score 2):

Try **pyinstaller**. I also do PySide2 projects and this installer works fine for me at least for windows applications. See https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/.